# Programatically add module block to dashboard

Tags: 7, blocks

Is there a way in which from my .module file I can assign a block in a specific region from Dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a simple way by mentioning a region key to the $blocks array in the HOOK_block_info(). Follow the code for reference,

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_block_info()
     * @return array
     */
    function my_module_block_info() {
      $blocks = array();
      $blocks['leaderboard'] = array(
        'info' => t('Leaderboard'),
        'status' => 1,
        'region' => 'dashboard_main',
        'weight' => 99,
        'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
      );

      return $blocks;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .install file you can add following sql (change the appropriate values)

```
db_query("INSERT INTO {blocks} VALUES ('gjg', '0', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 'my*', '')");
```

Answer (score 0):

yes. see [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) for **region**